# Excel generation in java

Tags: java, android, apache-poi, jxl, jxls

In Apache poi is there any provision for setting link between different sheets(For example i have an index page in my excel sheet which contains links to all my sheets. Can we do this for dynamic excel generation )? Is there any other libraries available for  doing the same?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes that's possible, here is some example code:

```
Cell cell = sheet.createRow(0).createCell(0);
cell.setCellValue("Worksheet Link");
HSSFHyperlink link = new HSSFHyperlink(HSSFHyperlink.LINK_DOCUMENT);
link.setTextMark("'Target Sheet'!A1");
cell.setHyperlink(link);
```

`Target Sheet` is the name of the sheet to which the link should switch to and `A1` is the target cell.

Answer (score 1):

You can use setAddress Method also.

```
HSSFHyperlink linkToSheet=new HSSFHyperlink(HSSFHyperlink.LINK_DOCUMENT);
linkToSheet.setAddress("ToSheet!A115");
```

Comment: version that i have using is not supporting the setAddress method. Anyway thanks for your quick response.